# ABC a triangle with orthocenter and circumcenter at (9,5) and (0,0) respectively if equation of side BC is 2x-y=1 , then find possible coords of A?

Tags: geometry

> Q) ABC is a triangle having orthocenter and circumcenter at (9,5) and
>   (0,0) respectively . If equation of side BC is 2x-y=1 , then find
>   possible coordinates of  A ?

**My attempt:**

Since circumcenter lies at origin we have orthocenter = 3* centroid coords

$x_{1}+x_{2}+x{3}=9$

$y_{1}+y_{2}+y_{3}=5$

Now im taking $(x_{1},y_{1})$ as coords of A and other coords as B,C.

Now since B,C  lies on given line $2x-y=10$ we have

$2(x_{2}+x_{3}) - (y_{2}+y{3}) =20$

Then substituting values from our first two equations we get

$y-2x=7$ which is a line where all possible values of A lie.

Now i wrote another equation for a line passing through A , orthocenter and $\perp (2x-y=10)$

Hence we have $x+2y=19$ , i equated this with our previous eqn $y-2x=7$ and im getting coords of A as $(1,9)$

But correct answer is $(\frac{79}{15},\frac{103}{15})$

Where am i going wrong , also shorter ways to solve this problem are always welcome .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point $(1,9)$ is the correct answer if the line passing through B and C is $2x-y=10$.

---

If $M$ is the midpoint of $BC$, then $OM$ is parallel to $AH$ and the length of $OM$ is equal to half of the length of $AH$.

Since $M$ is the foot of the perpendicular from $O$ to the line $2x-y=10$, we obtain $M = (4,-2)$.

Therefore $(9,5) -(x_1,y_1) = AH = 2(OM)= (8,-4).$

Thus $(x_1,y_1) = (9,5) - (8,-4) = (1,9).$